# NetSuite SuiteScript Performance Logging

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Are there any logs in NetSuite that provide information regarding SuiteScript performance? For example, when I save a purchase order, I'd like to be able to see all of the SuiteScripts that executed (including SuiteScripts from 3rd party bundles) and their runtimes. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for asking this...I realized I had the same need when I saw this.  Now I've installed the bundle so I hope it works as advertised :)

Comment: For anyone trying to use this APM tool, I found a useful trick. After any page has loaded, you can double click on the netsuite logo on the top left to get summary performance metrics - nice hidden feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the *Application Performance Monitor* bundle. I believe there is documentation in Help/SuiteAnswers about installing and managing it, but it will show you exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Any idea how this works behind the scenes? Does it have access to some hidden APIs giving access to performance stats of suitescripts?

Comment: My educated guess would be that it can access the NetSuite database directly and reports that way, but I don't have any evidence or confirmation of that.

Comment: Found the answer in the FAQ: "Will installation of the APM cause slower performance in my NetSuite account?

No. The SuiteApp reads from data stored in the back end. It does not create any additional overhead for your existing customizations aside from the scripts used to display the dashboard."

Answer (score 1):

As I just found out, you can install the <strike>Script Performance Monitor Bundle (Bundle ID: 38106) or</strike> Application Performance Monitor SuiteApp (Bundle ID: 67350).  Looks like 38106 has been replaced with 67350.  This provides a performance dashboard and a bunch of tools for monitoring and checking performance of records, scripts etc.